# SCNSceneRenderer ARFaceAnchor anchor detection distance

Tags: arkit, aranchor

I have been messing with ARKit for some time now. One thing I noticed when using Apples ARKitFaceExample is that there is a specific distance, where my face is still largely in the view, that is just stops receiving delegate calls for anchor updates. Is there a specific distance? I have been trying to find something that touches on that in the documentation but I do not see anything. Supposedly you can detect multiple faces but I do not see how more than one face could be within the cameras view at the same time without the distance exceeding the area where is seems to work. I was just wondering if anyone else has run into this issue.

Thanks, 
B

Comment: I've been measuring the max camera-to-eyes distance from FaceAnchor. The Anchor start loosing track at around 0.9 meter. Currently looking to overcome this issue too~ Maybe tracking it directly with the depth map could be ok, but sounds tough tho